# Internal and external gateway API methods

Tags: api, rest

What’s the best practice to differentiate the api calls from internal and external gateway. Is it recommended to create two api methods (secured and not secured)

Comment: the best practice is to avoid potential security holes and provide only secured endpoints

Comment: For internal calls I don’t need to verify the user. For external calls other than token verification it requires the principal check

Comment: why do you trust internal users, and even more - how you can even distinguish between them?

Comment: That’s the challenge, the only way currently it can be identified by an additional param coming in Authorization header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same Auth header as you do for external consumers and check the permissions for the actual consumer. Another way is just having two APIs.